# Custom error page use filter action mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-errors, asp.net-mvc-filters

My application use **MVC4**, **Entity Framework 6**. I want custom Actions return to **page error (500, 404, 403)** when an error occurs use Filter Action on MVC.

Currently, I'm using `Application_Error` method in file **Global.asax** to return page error, but it not working when action call from AJAX.

Ex:

This is page

```
[ExecuteCustomError]
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    Rerurn View();
}
```

This is view returned after AJAX call

```
[ExecuteCustomError]
public ActionResult ReturnView()
{
    //If return error code, i have return message error here.
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: What is the code of `ExecuteCustomError` ?

Comment: Have you added your error page in shared view folder

Comment: @CodeNotFound: This is the  Action filter desire :ExecuteCustomError.

Comment: Yep. I know. I ask it to just see what you have started to code for that question and help you to improve the code.

Comment: This is my idea for method ExecuteCustomError use filter action. My question, how to create method can execute custom error use filter action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't provided correct path of your error page. 
Like you need to add your error page in shared view folder then you can access this page. 
If your page is in the other folder then you have to specify the correct path of your error view page. 
Like below :

`return PartialView("~/Views/ErrorPartialView.cshtml", myModel);`

We have other options to call error page through web. In Config file you can do the below settings :

`<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx" />
    </httpErrors>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>`

**Here we go for Global Exception Filter :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCGlobalFilter.Filters
{
    public class ExecuteCustomErrorHandler : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "CommonExceptionPage"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Now you have to register your `ExecuteCustomErrorHandler` class in `Global.asax` file :**

```
/// <summary>
/// Application start event
/// </summary>
protected void Application_Start()
{
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

       // Calling Global action filter
       GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ExecuteCustomErrorHandler());
}
```

**You need to add `CommonExceptionPage` view in Shared folder :**

`CommonExceptionPage.cshtml` :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Execute Custom Error Handler";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Error.</h1>
    <h2 class="error">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @Laxman Gile! But I can use Filter action to redirect to action error page, not edit on web.config. In my question above, i can create action filter ExecuteCustomError to execute custom error.

Comment: Can you share executecustomerror action filter code

Comment: Oh! My question problem is method ExecuteCustomError. How to create method Action filter ExecuteCustomError??

Comment: no need to worry about it that will automatically redirect to you on error page check it now.

Comment: Thanks @Laxman Gile. I has been try it. Your code above working when  have exception occur on action. How to i can get status code to redirect to page error reference 404, 500, and 403. Here action filter, you need not declare on Application_Start method. Default it run when Action execute.

Comment: For 404, 500, and 403  you have to redirect trough web.config file that is the  common errors I have already added that pages in web.config file check above code.